# Explanation of an execution of maven-resources-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have inherited a project from another developer and there is a bit in the `pom.xml` that I don't quite understand. It's as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>filter</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>resources</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Can someone shed some light as to what it's trying to do? I think it's saying, "do filtering when running ANY generate-resources phase". Is this correct?

Comment: By using this explicit form (like other plugins do) the execution becomes inheritable to child projects. Also, setting an alternative execution id means that there won't be interference from another execution that is configured with inclusion/exclusion tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your interpretation is incorrect.

This is declaring an execution for the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/). This execution has an id of `filter` but this is just a technical identifier and it has no involvement in the build itself. This execution is bound to the [`generate-resources` phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) of the default life cycle and it invokes the [`resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) goal of that plugin.

Having said that, this is really strange and may be *completely* useless. By default, the `resources` goal of the `maven-resources-plugin` is already invoked in the default lifecycle in the `process-resources` phase (which is right after the `generate-resources` phase). What this goal does is to copy all of the resources of the project (i.e. what is under `src/main/resources` by default) to the main output directory (i.e. the `target` folder by default). Hence, this task will be performed twice: once in the `generate-resources` phase (per the execution in your POM) and another time in the `process-resources` phase by default.